# Raspberry Pi won't shut down

Tags: shutdown, raspbian-lite

There are plently of questions on this forum regarding shutdowns and how to perform them properly on a rpi, but I have not encountered anything like this before. Maybe I'm just being a linux n00b ¯_(ツ)_/¯ .

I recently burned a new image of Raspbian Stretch Lite on to my rpi model B. The system booted up fine, but when I went to shut it down, nothing would happen. After running `sudo shutdown -h now`, the system gives the standard "at [timestamp] system will halt" message, except it doesn't start shutting down; it just makes a newline with "pi@rpi~&" and pretends like nothing happens.

I've tried `sudo shutdown -h -t 0`, `sudo halt`, `sudo reboot`, `poweroff` and any other variations of those commands I could think of. Every time it spits out a new line and pretends I didn't even enter the command. The shutdown sequence just doesn't start. No errors are printed out. Why won't the system halt? Is there a fix?

Comment: Does 'tail -f /var/log/syslog' report anything useful ? Have you setup any cron jobs ?

Comment: @CoderMike tail doesnt report anything relevant, the problem does seem to occur only if I run apt-get upgrade. Rn im just unplugging, which isnt healthy for my sd card but sometimes i gotta reboot